# How to select specific span out of several dynamically generated by Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

My webpage shows data of several items - I use a handlebars loop (as seen below) to generate and populate the content and divs for each item. I don't have a static number of items, there could be roughly 0 to 50.

Inside each item is a button that, when pressed, starts a timer script that needs to change the text inside the item's div to count down the time using  `document.querySelector('#runTest')`. The button passes the database ID of the 'agent' it's inside to allow the script to do the test.

How would I only change the text of the span of the 'agent' that the button was pressed inside? Could I use handlebars to change the span id?

```
{{#each agent}}
  <div class="controls">
    <button id="runTest" onclick="runTest('{{this.id}}')">Run Test</button> <br>
    <span id="runTestTimer"></span><br>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```